# Why dynamic scaffolding with Grails doesn't work proprely?

Tags: grails

I've tried to scaffold dynamically some domains in GRAILS , but after adding items into database they doesn't show up in the listing view (User/index) in this case  :

User.groovy

```
package scaffold_test

class User {

    String username
    String address
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

UserController.groovy

```
package scaffold_test

class UserController {
        def scaffold=true
        def index() { }
    }
```

so after running the application, I can see the User controller in the Grails home page,I can add Users, and I can see the added instances via DbConsole. But i can't list the instances in the User/index view. Thanks !

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Delete `def index() { }` to let the scaffolding generate all of the methods.